# Compaq Presario V2000 Vista/7 trial virtualization

Tags: virtualization

I am currently studying for an A-Plus certification to which was recently added troubleshooting Windows 7 to the exam. You also have to be very familiar with Vista as well. I only have XP on my Compaq Presario V2000, but I wanted to set it up ( I believe I have the minimum requirements for both ) so that I could run trial versions of Vista and 7  virtually.Windows 2000 is also on the exam. Is there an easy legal way to do this? I wouldn't mind partitioning my HDD for the four operating systems either. Thnx if you have any ideas, JLS

Comment: Legal questions are outside of the scope of SU.   You seem to know you can get trial copies.  Why not get them and try it?  What's your actual question/problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a trial of Windows 7 [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx).

It would appear MS has removed all the Vista trial versions, I cant seem to find any.  I didnt even bother with 2000.